# Banned from editing question even if suggested edits are mostly approved

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I am banned from editing question in AE. My total edits in Android Enthusiasts are 28 and 26 edits got approved while only 2 got rejected. But still I don't know I am being banned from editing questions.

Have I done something wrong? or Have edited many questions?

Comment: This was done manually, by a moderator. I've asked the person responsible to chime in here.

Comment: Your edits seem fine to me, maybe it was a mistake / misclick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was my fault — I got you confused with someone else.  I need to be more careful when moderating from mobile.

I've removed the ban.  Sorry about that :(